# How to show the selected value in select box during edit in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have created a form with a select box to show the list of user name once the user name is selected i am passing a stringified object as value to firebase.
When i try to edit the form i would like to show the value which was selected during submission.
Can anyone tell me how to show the selected value in the select box when the form is in edit mode.
I am using redux form.

```
    <select
  {...input} className="form-control">
  <option value="" disabled>{selectPlaceHolder}</option>
  {Object.keys(datas).map((key) => {
    return (
      <option value={JSON.stringify({id: key, name: datas[key].name})} key={key}>
        {datas[key].name}
      </option>
    );
  })}
</select>
```

Comment: Store a selected value in state's property name it currentSelectedValue regardless/before you send it to firebase.Then Pass a flag, if `edit===true` then pass that selected value. Did my assumption cleared it for you ? . Can you eloborate more please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React makes this even easier for you. Instead of defining selected on each option, you can (and should) simply write value={JSON.stringify({id: editData.id, name: editData.name})} on the select tag itself`

```
<select
  {...input} className="form-control" value={JSON.stringify({id: editData.id, name: editData.name})}>
  <option value="" disabled>{selectPlaceHolder}</option>
  {Object.keys(datas).map((key) => {
    return (
      <option value={JSON.stringify({id: key, name: datas[key].name})} key={key}>
        {datas[key].name}
      </option>
    );
  })}
</select>
```